# How to localize custom Done button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, localization, uinavigationbar

I use `Done` button in my custom view and I'd like to make its title localizable. I know that system `Done` button from `UINavigationBar` is already localized and it would be perfect to get it's localized strings somehow. Is there a way to do this?

Using the whole `UINavigationBar` only because of localized `Done` button seems to be inappropriate.

Clarification: the point is to use the same localized strings, that system uses.

Comment: You can find the strings in UIKit.framework in the simulator. I believe it is possible to load them directly from the UIKit bundle, but that's unwise; copying them out is safer (note that there may be copyright issues if you do this for long strings!).

Comment: @tc. It sounds like exactly what I need! But I can't open that Localizable.strings files from UIKit.framework in readable format.

Comment: TextWrangler should do the trick. Alternatively, if you use bash, `alias plist-dump='plutil -convert xml1 -o /dev/stdout --`.

Comment: TextWrangler did it! Could you please create an answer from your comment, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an official way to get standard strings from the OS, but it's highly likely that all the strings will be in localized strings files, and most of those are present on the simulator (it won't have strings from apps that aren't present on the simulator, but should have almost all the strings from frameworks).

The simulator's framework directory is relative to your Xcode install directory and something like this (typing it from memory, change the version as appropriate):

```
Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/
```

To start with, I'd look in `UIKit.framework/en.lproj/*.strings` (or English.lproj or en_US.lproj). Strings files are plists and will generally be binary plists on device (such files start with "bplist00"). There are various ways to open these: TextWrangler will automatically display plists as XML, and the command-line tool `plutil` will convert to other formats. I use the bash alias

```
alias plist-dump='plutil -convert xml1 -o /dev/stdout --'
```

When you've found the string, you have a couple of options:

- Load it directly from the framework at runtime with something like

  ```
  [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:...] localizedStringForKey:@"DONE" value:nil table:...]
  ```

  This is **not recommended**. Yhere's no guarantee that it will work on a different OS version. (In practice, a string like "Done" probably won't move, but the alternative is easy enough that it's not worth the fuss.)
- Copy the strings into your project. I don't know of a tool to automatically do this and merge with your existing Localizable.strings, but it probably exists somewhere and would not be too difficult to write. *Slightly* legally dubious (but not much more so than copying strings by eye for the languages you care about); I would definitely avoid doing it on a prerelease SDK to avoid concerns about Apple's NDA.
- Copy the whole strings file into e.g. `UIKit.strings` and use something like `NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"DONE",@"UIKit",nil)`. Likely to be a copyright infringement!

In practice, I think Apple is unlikely to care about copying a handful of strings/images from iOS into an iOS app. Copying them into an Android app is another matter entirely...

Answer (score 1):

Just add needed localization in project settings, all system stuff like done button will be localized by device locale if you added it, else it willbe on default language which you also should set up.

For custom button:

```
[self.myButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"my localizable title", @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It also valid for any NSString in your project.

```
NSString *someText = NSLocalizedString(@"my localizable title", @"");
self.myLabel.text = someText;
```

You should make your app localizable anyway by adding needed localizations.

After that just follow this instructions:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

But I really recommend to you to do this in the end of project.

Comment: My Done button is just a UIButton from my custom view, it's not a system button.

Comment: Oh I see. Are you going to use it without xib?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to set title programmatically.

Comment: You mean that I have to make localized string by myself anyway? The point was to use these strings from system button...

Comment: Huh... Not sure, try to create system done UIBarButtonItem and take it's title. But looks like localizable string much effective and easy.

Comment: Sounds interesting! I'll try it tomorrow. Thanks!